# How can I clean my form after a ngrx succeeded action?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a reactive form:

```
const createFormGroup = (dataItem?: Usuario) => {
  if (dataItem) {
    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(dataItem.id),
      nome: new FormControl(dataItem.nome),
      cidade: new FormControl(dataItem.cidade)
    });
  }
  return new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(),
    nome: new FormControl(''),
    cidade: new FormControl('')
  });
};
```

This is my template:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="formGroup">
   <input formControlName="nome" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Nome">
   <input formControlName="cidade" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
   <button id="my-element" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Complete
   </button>
</form>
```

After I click on "submit", I make a dispatch that save my data using a ngrx effect:

```
save() {
  const user = this.formGroup.value;
  if (user.id === null) {
    this.store.dispatch(createUser({ user: user }));
  } else {
    this.store.dispatch(updateUser({ user: user }));
  }
}
```

This is my effect:

```
public saveUser$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(createUser),
    switchMap((action) =>
      this.usuarioService.save(action.user).pipe(
        map(() => loadUsers()),
        catchError((error) => of(loadUsers()))
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Someone can tell me if have one way to clear my reactive when my effect don't go to catchError?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a step by step example. It looks like a lot of effort, but is quite a common pattern and reasonably easy to set up. Let me know if you have any probs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to clear the form after you’re sure the action has been successfully dispatched, I would set up a simple service with an observable that is updated by your effect when `this.usuarioService.save` is successful:

**Effect:**

You will need to import `Subject` to your effect file:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

Then add a service like the following. This could be in a separate file, but to keep things simple, add it to the top of your effect file, immediately below all the "imports"

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClearFormService {
  private clearFormSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  clearForm$ = this.clearFormSource.asObservable();
  clearForm() {
    this.clearFormSource.next(true);
  }
}
```

Next, add this service to the constructor in your effect class:

```
constructor(private clearFormService: ClearFormService) { }
```

If there are already references in your constructor add:

```
private clearFormService: ClearFormService
```

...to the end.

You can then update the observable in this service when `this.usuarioService.save` is successful. Notice curly brackets have been added to the `map`. There are 'more rxjs' approaches, but I think this is fine:

```
public saveUser$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(createUser),
    switchMap((action) =>
      this.usuarioService.save(action.user).pipe(
        map(() => {
            this.clearFormService.clearForm(); // Updates your service
            return loadUsers();
        }),
        catchError((error) => of(loadUsers()))
      )
    )
  )
);
```

**Component With Form:**

Then in the component with your form, you will need to import `ClearFormService` from your effect file and add it to the constructor, the same as was done in the effect file. You may also need to import `subscription`:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
```

You can then subscribe to `clearForm$`, and clear the form whenever a response is received.

```
clearFormSubscription = new Subscription();

ngOnInit() {
    this.clearFormSubscription = this.clearFormService.clearForm$.subscribe(response => {
        this.formGroup.reset()
        console.log('Clear Form Here');
    })
  }
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe onDestroy!

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.clearFormSubscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

You could set up a solution that uses your ngrx store, but I think this would be over-engineering things.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to do it ngrx way, call another action from your effect on the success.

```
saveUser$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(createUser),
        switchMap((action) =>
            this.usuarioService.save(action.user).pipe(
                map(() => {
                    loadUsers();
                    return new clearFormAction();
                }),
                catchError((error) => of(loadUsers()))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

- Reset your form data to empty(initial state in general cases) in the reducer for `clearFormAction()`.

```
case clearFormAction: {
    return {
        ...state,
        id: '',
        nome: '',
        cidade: ''
    };
}
```

- Subscribe to the store form data in your component ngOnInit()

```
this.storeFormData$ = this.store.select(formData);
this.storeFormData.subscribe(formData => {
    this.formGroup.setValue(formData);
});
```

- So whenever your `this.usuarioService.save()` is success your form will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just observe state in the component and do all the resets if a particular property indicates that an operation was performed successfully.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.watchOperations();
    // ...
}

watchOperations(): void {
    this.store
    .pipe(
        select(state => state.todos.succeeded)
    )
    .subscribe(succeeded => {
        if (succeeded) {
            this.store.dispatch(LOAD());
            this.formSubmitted = false;
            this.form.reset(this.formDefaults);
        }
    });
}
```

When it comes to the effect:

```
createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ADD),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
      return this.todosService.add(payload)
        .pipe(
          map(() => ({ type: '[Todos] Add Success' })),
          catchError(() => of({ type: '[Todos] Add Fail' }))
        );
    })
));
```

Component:

```
addTodo(): void {
    this.formSubmitted = true;

    if (this.form.valid) {
        this.store.dispatch(ADD({
            payload: {
                ...this.form.value,
                done: false
            } as ITodo
        }));
    }
}
```

And reducer:

```
// ...
on(ADD, (state, action) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        processed: action.payload,
        processing: true
    };
}),
on(ADD_SUCCESS, (state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        processing: false,
        succeeded: true
    };
}),
on(ADD_FAIL, (state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        processing: false,
        succeeded: false
    };
}),
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **This.formGroup.reset()** to reset you form based on the condition where you want to clear the form values

Comment: this.formGroup.reset() is not recognized in the ngrx effect file, how you sugest to trigger this in my component? maybe a new action that emit a value from a observable that is subscribed in my component? I'm looking for ideas of how i can trigger this in my ngrx effect